# How can I create a select list without specifying its List of Values?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form which has two select lists. The first one is prepopulated with an SQL query and has a dynamic action to set the value of the second list based on what is selected in the first.

I tested this out with a select list-textbox combination and it works just fine. However when I try to change the textbox into a select list then I am forced to also provide a "list of values" which overwrites my dynamic action.

How can I create a select list without specifying its List of Values?

Some clarification about my situation.

I have 2 tables: Wines and Winegroups.

```
+---------+------------+
|  Wines  | Winegroups |
+---------+------------+
| WineID  | GroupID    |
| Name    | Name       |
| GroupID |            |
+---------+------------+
```

In APEX I have a form like this:

[image]

When the page is loaded, the first select list will get filled with values using this query:

```
select distinct Name, GroupID from Winegroups
```

Furthermore there is a dynamic action defined like this which fires whenever a group is selected. This is supposed to change the values inside the 'Wines' select list.

**Event**: Change
**Selection type**: Items on `P5_GROUPID`
**Action**: Set value
**Page items to submit**: `P5_GROUPID`
**Affected elements**: Items on `P5_NAME`

```
select distinct Wines.Name, Wines.WineID id
from Wines
left join Winegroups
 on Wines.GroupID = Winegroups.GroupID
where Winegroups.Name = :P5_GROUPID
order by 1
```

The second select list uses the same query. When I execute my program the first select list is filled with groups nicely but the second one never gets any values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in apex 4.1, it is no longer necessary to use a dynamic action to get one select list to populate based on the value selected in a prior one.  To get the functionality you want, you should be able to just do:

1. Disable or remove the current dynamic action.
2. Go into the Wines select list page item (`P5_NAME`).
3. In the List of Values section, for the Cascading LOV Parent Items field, select the winegroup select list item (`P5_GROUPID`).
4. The Page Items to Submit field will appear in that same section.  Select the `P5_GROUPID` there as well.
5. In the list of values definition, put your query just as you wrote it above:

```
select distinct Wines.Name, Wines.WineID id  
from Wines  
left join Winegroups  
on Wines.GroupID = Winegroups.GroupID  
where Winegroups.Name = :P5_GROUPID  
order by 1;
```

Edit to answer to question in comments:

When you do:

```
select distinct Name, GroupID 
from Winegroups;
```

for a select list it displays name to the user, but stores the groupid.  If you wanted to use name, you could do:

```
select name d, name r 
from winegroups;
```

as your winegoup select list query.  Then the value in P5_GROUPID would actually be the name and you could join it to winegroups.name in the wines select list query.  Of course you should also rename P5_GROUPID if you were going to do this.

But I would probably just leave it the way it is.  This way you actually don't need the join in your second query.  You could just make it:

```
select wines.name, wines.wineid 
from wines where groupid = :P5_GROUP_ID.
```

This would be the cleanest implementation.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure what you meant with your answer so I updated my question with some relevant information. Could you tell me if that changes how you would solve it?

Comment: The same method should work, but I rewrote the answer to specifically address the situation.

Comment: Cheers, this is working now! (although I had to change `Winegroups.Name` to `Winegroups.GroupID`).

Comment: When you do:  select distinct Name, GroupID from Winegroups

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was it right after I posted the comment. Thank you for your help, you've cleared up a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I put the whole thing in the answer above.  Couldn't fit it into a comment.